# Как настроить поддомен, когда сервер по любому url направляет на главный проект?

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, apache2, apache2.2

На моем VDS с Ubuntu 16.04 есть сертификат SSL только на site.ru. Хочу сделать поддомен blog.site.ru, на который SSL не распространяется, добавил его в config'и, однако при переходе на поддомен он использует страницы проекта из основного домена. Должен использовать /var/www/blog ,но использует, что и основной - /var/www/site
Обе папки - разные Laravel-5.5 проекты

000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin 123@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public/

ServerName site.ru
ServerAlias www.site.ru

<Directory /var/www/site/public>
    Allowoverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

blog.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin 123@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/blog/public/

ServerName blog.site.ru
ServerAlias www.blog.site.ru

<Directory /var/www/blog/public>
    Allowoverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin 123@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/public/

    ServerName site.ru
    ServerAlias www.site.ru

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /SSL/domain_name.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /SSL/private.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /SSL/chain.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /var/www/site/public>
        Allowoverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

ports.conf:

```
Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Файл .htaccess проекта /var/www/site

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
# RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

apache2.conf:

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
Include ports.conf
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-
Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" 
combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Comment: Так а проблема собственно в чем? Что не создается?

Comment: @defrag при переходе по url поддомена используются страницы проекта из основного домена. Должен открывать проект /var/www/blog , а открывается /var/www/site

Comment: Апач сам никуда ничего не перенаправляет. В конфиге об это ни сказано ни слова. Если вы будете заходить на свой поддомен именно как "http", а не "https" то должно работать. Если же вы оказываетесь при этом на странице https:основной-сайт, значит у вас в каком то из файлов вашего поддомена стоит перенаправление

Comment: @Mike Вот именно что я оказываюсь на http: blog.site.ru, но который по неясной мне причине использует проект  /var/www/site ,а не blog, хотя в config папки я указал корректно

Comment: Получается виртуал хост вообще не сработал. посмотрите где и как описаны остальные хосты на 80 порту. в приведенном вами конфиге этого вообще нет, значит они в каком то другом конфиге описаны

Comment: @Mike все облазил, что мог, ничего не нашел. Установка сервера свежая, ничего кроме этих проектов на них не ставил. Можете подсказать, где конкретнее стоит посмотреть?

Comment: Странно это все. У вас там симлинков случайно на файловой системе нет среди этих документрутов?

Comment: Но факт остается фактом, 80 порт для основного домена вообще не описан. С такой конфигурацией он в принципе не способен открывать основной сайт на 80 порту. Ищите все упоминания "80" во всех файлах в каталоге конфигов апача. Либо вы не видите какой то конфиг, либо 80 порт у вас обслуживает не апач.

Comment: @defrag ну, у меня в папке /etc/apache2/sites-enabled хранятся файлы-ссылки на файлы /etc/apache2/sites-available. Вы об этом?

Comment: Нет, это файлы конфигураций, и в убунтовском апаче так и задумано. Я про возможные симлинки в DocumentRoot виртуалхостов. Например, /var/www/blog это симлинк на /var/www/site. Как-то так. Если ничего такого нет, прицепите к вопросу все конфиги из каталога sites-enabled и ports.conf

Comment: @defrag Нет, doceumentroot-ы в папках это разные Laravel проекты. Без файлов-ссылок. Конфиги прикрепил.

Comment: В верхнем конфиге не видно VirtualHost в начале, если там вдруг не `*:80` это могло бы все объяснить ...

Comment: @Mike там 443, ведь основной домен защищен SSL сертификатом и по 80 порту не работает

Comment: Какая то у вас путаница. в первом конфиге никакого 443 порта быть не должно, он ведь у вас описывается во втором конфиге, который как раз называется _ssl, и всякие там SSLEngine on вообще то в нем должны быть, а не в первом. И мы опять вернулись к тому с чего начали, основной сайт на 80 порту не описан нигде, но открывается. Значит вы не все видите, раз уж кто то додумался написать ssl часть в не ssl конфиг, то он же мог что нибудь написать в основном httpd.conf, так что смотрите и конфиги в других каталогах

Comment: по текущей конфигурации выходит, что на 80 порту есть только ваш блог и он должен открываться даже если попытаться зайти на 80 порт основного домена. но у вас наоборот открывается основной, значит он где то описан ...

Comment: @Mike я изменил конфиги, согласно вашим комментариям. Но теперь браузер выдает "Этот сайт не может обеспечить безопасное соединение" и не открывает ни домен, ни поддомен =(

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас установлен Nginx как прокси для Apache, в таком случае для него тоже нужно добавить конфигурационный файл нового хоста. Так же попробуйте поиграть с портами,  в настройках вирт хостов. Не думаю что это связано с SSL. Ну или проблемы в DNS записях.

Comment: Nginx не установлен. В dns записях есть правило, которое направляет все *.site.ru на ip хоста. А что можно сделать с портами?  Если изменить их - страницы станут недоступны.